# react native stackNavigation header

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing a little problem with the header included with the stackNavigator in react-native.

i'v got two views that i'm navigating between, Skatebay and Profile. 
When I use the stackNavigator it add's a top-bar "header" to the Skatebay view, how can i remove it, if not possible, can i style it to look like the header i've already created?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import s from './styles/main.js';

class skatebay extends React.Component{

  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (

  <View style={s.container}>

      <View style={s.toolbar}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={s.toolbarButton} onPress={() => navigate('Profile')}
          title="Profile">
          <Image style={s.toolIcon} source={require('./gfx/profile.png')}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={s.toolbarTitle} onPress={alert}>
          <Image style={s.logo} source={require('./gfx/logos.png')}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={s.toolbarButton} onPress={alert}>
          <Image style={s.toolIcon} source={require('./gfx/settings.png')}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      </View>
    );
    }
}
```

Profile view

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Profile',
    };
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>profile</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const skatebayApp = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: skatebay},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('skatebayApp', () => skatebayApp);
```

I'm talking about the blue/gray header above the white header i've created.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want the default header of StackNavigator, you can pass none to StackNavigatorConfig https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig

```
const skatebayApp = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: skatebay},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen}
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't belive it was so hard to find. You saved my day